# Opening a JAR resource as a FileStream

Tags: java, jar

I have a project where I want to access a resource in a JAR from another project.  It's not on my classpath, so ClassLoader is not an option.  I tried:

```
new FileInputStream("C:\\mydir\\my.jar!\\myresource.txt");
```

and received a FileNotFoundException.

JarInputStream might be a possibility, but I want the flexibility of the input filename being a jar resource or just a file on the system (user decides).  Is there a class that can do this or do I have to build one myself?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but jar files are basically zip files, so if you can read something out of a zip file you can read it out of a jar in the same way -- maybe that helps expand your search.

Comment: @Mark - JAR files are essentially ZIP files, but only for the moment. Rumour has it that the JAR format is changing in Java 7. Hopefully, using the appropriate abstraction classes will future-proof any JAR manipulation code (see the `java.util.jar` package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URLs are your friend](http://blogs.oracle.com/jag/date/20030822)

`URL.openStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the desicion with the "!" symbol doesn't work.

Have a look here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4730642

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [URLClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). I've done something similar to this before, and it seems to work (though you may need to muck around with your security policy file, if you're in a secure JVM).

Answer (score 0):

try using java.net.JarURLConnection

URL url = new URL("jar:file:C:\mydir\my.jar!\myresource.txt");

JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Answer (score 0):

```
  private InputStream twistLid(File jar, String resource) throws IOException {
    return new URL("jar:" + jar.toURI() + "!" + resource).openStream();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the work of many above, here's an example in groovy, listing the text contained in 'resource.txt' inside a folder named 'reources' at the root level of a jar file

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*
import java.util.jar.*

def getJarResourceAsStream(String jarName, String resource) throws IOException {
    def resourceStr = 'jar:' + (new File(jarName)).toURI() + '!' + resource
    return new URL(resourceStr).openStream()
}

def inputStream = getJarResourceAsStream('/some/file/path/myJar.jar', '/resources/resource.txt')

def reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader)
String line
while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line)
}
```